# Generating sitemap.xml on multi stores

Tags: magento, sitemap.xml

I have setup multistores on one Magento installation and all the stores are on different servers. I have created symlinks for each of them. 
Now I want to generate sitemap.xml for each store. I have created a folder called sitemaps on my root directory, inside sitemaps I’ve created folders for each store. (i.e. store1, store2 inside sitemaps). Now I’m generating sitemap.xml inside them folders for each store. I’ve also add the following line in .htaccess of store1.com:

`RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ http://www.mainserver.com/sitemaps/store1/sitemap.xml [NC]`

(found this help here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/59388/) 
Now if I type www.store1.com/sitemap.xml, I should be able to see the xml for that store but I’m getting 404 Not Found error. 
Any ideas?

Comment: and your files are generated and symlinks are valid? and you can access the files from their absolute url ?

Comment: Yes, the sitemap.xml are getting generated and syslinks are valid. And also I can access the files by typing www.mainserver.com/sitemaps/store1/sitemap.xml. Its just when I type www.store1.com/sitemap.xml, I get this error.

Comment: if you can access them directly then your rewrite rules are wrong

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [Magento stack](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89923/sitemap-for-multistore-shop)

NOTE: I tried this way it always works.

First, create a new folder called sitemaps in the root of your website, then create subfolders for each domain.

```
/sitemaps/domain_1/
/sitemaps/domain_2/
```

Then login to the Magento admin and navigate to – **catatlog -> google sitemap**

Create or edit the sitemap listings for each store and set the “path to sitemap” field to be the path you created for the store.

```
/sitemaps/domain_1/
/sitemaps/domain_2/
```

Update your robots.txt file. To make sure that the search engine spiders are properly directed to the new sitemaps. You may need to update or create the robots.txt file. Edit the robots.txt file and add the following lines at the top —

```
# Website Sitemap
Sitemap: http://www.domain_1.com/sitemaps/domain_1/sitemap.xml  
Sitemap: http://www.domain_2.com/sitemaps/domain_2/sitemap.xml
```

Finally, if your site uses the Apache web server engine, you should update the **.htaccess** file in the root of your website to direct any other sitemap requests to the proper place.
Locate the following line below the line that reads —  RewriteEngine on

And add the following redirect statements below it —

```
# Sitemap: http://www.domain_1.com/sitemaps/domain_1/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain_1\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemaps/domain_1/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]

# Sitemap: http://www.domain_2.com/sitemaps/domain_2/sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*domain_2\.com$
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemaps/domain_2/sitemap.xml [NC,L,R=301]
```